# Determinar posiciones en un vector en C#

Tags: c#, .net

No he encontrado solución para este ejercicio académico que consiste en averiguar la posición donde se encuentra el número de menor valor de un array.

No me muestra posiciones dándome siempre cero y al imprimir la variable "Menor" no tiene sentido el valor que toma.

---

```
namespace PRAC09A02
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int Valor = 3;
            int[] Vector = new int[Valor];
            int Posicion = 0;
            int Menor = Vector[0];
            Boolean OK = false;

            for (int count = 0; count < Valor; count++)
            {
                OK = false;
                while (OK == false)
                {
                    Console.Write("\nINTRODUCIR VALOR: ");

                    if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Vector[count]))
                    {
                        OK = true;
                    }
                    else
                        Console.Write("\n\tNO SE PUDO CONVERTIR A TIPO INT");
                }
            }
            Console.Write(Funciones.PosicionValor(Vector, Posicion, Menor, Valor));
            Console.Write("\nPULSAR CUALQUIER TECLA PARA FINALIZAR...");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
    class Funciones
    {
        public static int PosicionValor (int [] Vector, int Valor,int Posicion, int Menor)
        {
            for(int Contador = 0; Contador < Valor; Contador++){
                if(Vector[Contador] < Menor){
                    Menor = Vector[Contador];
                    Posicion = Contador;
                }
            }
            return (Posicion);
        }


    }
}
```

---

Comment: `int Menor = Vector[0];` al inicio lo pone a 0 (el vector se inicializa con defaults) tendrías que retomar el valor de `Vector[0]` luego de rellenar el vector y antes de llamar a la función que busca el menor

Comment: Aclara tu pregunta. El metodo `PosicionValor` debe de retornar el valor menor del vector o el indice del valor menor del array?

Comment: El índice del valor menos del array, quedó resuelto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Primero,*** que si necesitas la posición del valor menor del vector no es necesario pasar ni el valor, ni la posición y el menor. Con solo pasar el vector es suficiente para obtener el índice.

***Segundo***, cuando llamas a `PosicionValor` en el main el parámetro `Valor` lo estas colocando de ultimo, pero en la firma del método va de segundo.

Te dejo el método modificado:

```
public static int PosicionValor(int[] Vector)
{
    int Posicion = 0;

    for (int Contador = 1; Contador < Vector.Length; Contador++)
    {
        if (Vector[Posicion] > Vector[Contador])
        {
            Posicion = Contador;
        }
    }
    return Posicion;
}
```

Y en el main lo llamas así:

```
Console.Write(Funciones.PosicionValor(Vector));
```

Si te fijas el propio vector ya contiene una propiedad `Length` la cual contiene el tamaño del vector.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora el código ha quedado mucho mas claro.

Comment: Si el array tuviera carácteres en vez de números, cómo se modificaría para poder obtener las posiciones de las repeticiones de una letra. Por ejemplo teniendo un string "Holaa" y bucando el carácter 'A' para que no devuelva como índices 3 y 4

Comment: El comentario ya se sale del ambito de lo que preguntas, es mejor que intentes hacer algo y cuando te encuentres con un problema entonces vuelves hacer una pregunta nueva.

Comment: Primero debes de definir si lo que vas a recorrer es una vector de caracteres o una cadena, y luego solo debes de comparar posicion por posicion el valor que buscas, y recuerdad que `A` no es lo mismo que `a`, por lo que deberas definir si tambien sera sencible a minuscula y mayuscula. Segundo que retornara tu metodo si un indice o varios indices.

Comment: Exacto sus valores ASCII son diferentes, retorna varios índices. Abriré una nueva consulta para esta duda. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

La variable `Menor` debes de inicializarla. Debes hacerlo dentro de la clase o método donde se vaya a utilizar. Dentro del método `PosicionValor`.

```
if(Vector[Contador] < Menor){
    Menor = Vector[Contador];
    Posicion = Contador;
}
```

Comment: Debes hacerlo dentro de la clase o método donde se vaya a utilizar. Dentro del método PosicionValor.

Comment: o luego de rellenar el vector, antes de llamar a la función así toma el primer valor del vector

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por vuestra ayuda!

Comment: Ok a la orden. Mucho animo!!!

Comment: ¿Solucionó tu problema, @nauumb? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde y te dará 2 puntos de reputación). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!